# Struts 2 jQuery grid load data from JSON string

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid

I found that we can load the `jqGird` with JSON string.

Please refer to [map JSON data to jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099777/map-json-data-to-jqgrid).

Is it possible to use this feature with `sjg:grid` tag?

I look at tag attribute and only find that the data can be loaded from a URL which will call a Struts action and that action returns a JSON data, but in my program I already have the JSON value and need to pass it to `jqGird`.

If the tag does not support data, what is the best way to use `jqGrid` which are included in  Struts 2 jQuery plugin.

Comment: I think it should be straightforward. Using grid to add row data.

Comment: @RomanC which one you mean: using sjg:grid or using the jqGrid directly?!

Comment: And can you guide me on how to do it with sjg:grid ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `dataType="local"` to the `sjg:grid` and remove `href` attribute. Then provide *row data* from the array. For example

```jsp
<sjg:grid
    id="gridtable"
    caption="Example (Editable/Multiselect)"
    dataType="local"
    pager="true"
    navigator="true"
    navigatorSearchOptions="{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}"
    navigatorAddOptions="{height:280, width:500, reloadAfterSubmit:true}"
    navigatorEditOptions="{height:280, width:500, reloadAfterSubmit:false}"
    navigatorEdit="true"
    navigatorView="true"
    navigatorViewOptions="{height:280, width:500}"
    navigatorDelete="true"
    navigatorDeleteOptions="{height:280, width:500,reloadAfterSubmit:true}"
    gridModel="gridModel"
    rowList="5,10,15"
    rowNum="5"
    rownumbers="true"
    editurl="%{editurl}"
    editinline="true"
    multiselect="true"
    onSelectRowTopics="rowselect"
    >

    <sjg:gridColumn name="id" index="id" title="Id" formatter="integer" editable="false" sortable="true" search="true" sorttype="integer" searchoptions="{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="name" index="name" key="true" title="Country Name" editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="true" search="true" sorttype="text"/>

</sjg:grid>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var mydata = [{id:"1",name:"Roman C"}];
    //for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++) $("#gridtable").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);
    $("#gridtable").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
        data: mydata
    }).trigger("reloadGrid");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The above code works perfect, it add rows for each grid load. If u want new data every time u can use this:

```
            var allParameters = $("#gridtable").jqGrid("getGridParam");
                        allParameters.data = myData;
                        $("#gridtable").trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Instead of:

```
      $("#gridtable").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
                            data: mydata
                        }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Also if u want to make an ajax call to action and fetch list and parse it to add to myData. Check this:

```
  $.ajax({
            url: "myAction.action", cache: false, dataType: 'json', data: "employeeId=" +
                    employeeIdList,
            success: function (data) {
                var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data.jsonResponse);
                var parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
                if (parsedData.hasResults) {
                    var myData = parsedData.jsonResults;
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        var allParameters = $("#gridtable").jqGrid("getGridParam");
                        allParameters.data = myData;
                        $("#gridtable").trigger('reloadGrid');

                    });
                }
            } });
```