# Struts 2 jquery chart load chart data with local data

Tags: jquery, struts2, flot, struts2-jquery-plugin, struts2-jquery-chart

I want to load chart data with a local data.

```jsp
 <sjc:chart
       id="chartPlaceHolder"
       cssStyle="width: 600px; height: 400px;"
       pie="true"
       pieLabel="true"
       dataType="local"        
   />
```

Then I used (as mentioned in [Refresh/Reload Flot In Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024474/refresh-reload-flot-in-javascript))

```js
//This data is created dynamically from a grid when grid completed 
var chartData= [
                { label: "Chrome",  data: 36.3, color: "#89A54E"},
                { label: "Other",  data: 0.8, color: "#3D96AE"}
            ];
var plot = $.plot($('#chartPlaceHolder'));
    plot.setData(chartData);
    plot.setupGrid();
    plot.draw();
```

I get some jquery exception `aB is undefined` in jquery APIs

Any comments ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing two additional parameters to `$.plot()`.

You should read the [basic usage](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/README.md#basic-usage).

> Create a placeholder div to put the graph in:
>
> ```
> <div id="placeholder"></div>
> ```
>
> You need to set the width and height of this div, otherwise the plot
>   library doesn't know how to scale the graph. You can do it inline like
>   this:
>
> ```
> <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px"></div>
> ```
>
> You can also do it with an external stylesheet. Make sure that the
>   placeholder isn't within something with a display:none CSS property -
>   in that case, Flot has trouble measuring label dimensions which
>   results in garbled looks and might have trouble measuring the
>   placeholder dimensions which is fatal (it'll throw an exception).
>
> Then when the div is ready in the DOM, which is usually on document
>   ready, run the plot function:
>
> ```
> $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, options);
> ```
>
> Here, data is an array of data series and options is an object with
>   settings if you want to customize the plot. Take a look at the
>   examples for some ideas of what to put in or look at the API
>   reference. Here's a quick example that'll draw a line from (0, 0) to
>   (1, 1):
>
> ```
> $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ [[0, 0], [1, 1]] ], { yaxis: { max: 1 } });
> ```

EDIT:

You can try below code. It's reloading the chart with data after the chart was created without data.

```jsp
<sjc:chart
    id="placeholder"
    cssStyle="width: 600px; height: 400px;"
    pie="true"
    pieLabel="true">
</sjc:chart>
<script>
  $(function(){
    var chartData= [
      { label: "Chrome",  data: 36.3, color: "#89A54E"},
      { label: "Other",  data: 0.8, color: "#3D96AE"}
    ];
    var series =  { pie: { show: true }};
    var o = {};
    o.data = chartData;
    o.series= series;
    $.struts2_jquery_chart.chart($("#placeholder"), o);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: you are correct. But as I initiate the chart with `sjc:chart` I don't know how to get and path the `data` and `option` I even tried to path them empty parameter but it did not worked. Could you tell me how can I get the plot object

Comment: Why do you initiate `sjc:chart`? flot is another library for charts.

Comment: `sjc:chart` uses flot under the hood. calling the `sjc:chart` will load all necessary `flot` and `flot.pie` chart js files

Comment: It's unclear what do you want, the data is in the format `[[]]`, but your data has different format. And you should privide it with `sjc:chartData` list or href attribute

Comment: Thanks @RomanC. The data could be an array of json string as mentioned in `http://www.pikemere.co.uk/blog/flot-how-to-create-pie-charts/` . Well let me ask this way.... please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326472/struts-2-jquery-grid-load-data-from-json-string which you have been answered. The question was about loading grid data locally. In that example the simple `$("#gridtable")` returned the jqGrid object  which then we could easily set its `data` and call `trigger("reloadGrid");` Is it possible to do this with `plot`

Comment: I'm not sure if you can get `plot` via  subscribing to `plotclick` or `plothover`. Let me know if it works for you. jqGrid is a function and it has different API.